# Asp.net core Incorrect redirect_url when use Facebook external login

Tags: asp.net, facebook, oauth, asp.net-core

I am working in a project required Facebook login using asp.net core following to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/).

Everything seem fine then I deploy it to my Ubuntu VPS. Since kestrel server is not a complete web server so I setup a Haproxy listens on https(443) which route to asp.net core app on port 1080(http). When I go to my website and click to Facebook login button I would get a error message form Facebook:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

I got this error message because the parameter redirect_uri is **http**:// instead of **https** which expected From facebook app configuration.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not specify the type of request scheme, this could generate a call with https and another with http, facebook will take this as a different url.

You just need to add this

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
       {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
       });
```

on your startup class (Startup.cs) under the "Configure" method.

Be sure to set this code before this.

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbOptions);
```

Comment: I have a asp.net core app with Facebook login integration running on Heroku and this is the only option working for me. Using the `UseForwardedHeaders` approach didn't do the job.

Comment: > Be sure to set this code before this. `app.UseFacebookAuthentication... ` 

For my .NET Core 2.1 app, this specifically was the missing piece. I had the HTTPS request scheme set, but `app.UseAuthentication();` line first. (Note the slight difference in the UseAuthentication() method in 2.1).

Comment: Doesn't apply to ASP NET CORE 3.1 FacebookAuthenticationMiddleware

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figured it out.
Firstly, we need to instal this package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides/).
Then put this piece of code in file Startup.cs

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
app.UseHttpMethodOverride();
```

before the line

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(...)
```

You can find more [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1036).

Comment: This is only required if you don't use `app.UseIISIntegration()` as it implicitly registers the forward headers already

Comment: @Tseng My Program.cs does have `host.UseIISIntegration()`. Where do you put that line of code in ?

Answer (score 1):

This can occur if you have a front-end proxy that is handling your Https.

Your proxy is managing the Https fine, but when it forwards the request to your Core app, it is a normal Http request. External Login will use the same Http/Https scheme that the incoming request is using.

To overcome the problem, two steps are required:

1. Configure your proxy to forward the protocol scheme.
2. Configure your app to process the forwarded protocol header to identify whether it is a Https request or not.

Step 1 depends on what proxy you are using. If it is Nginx, add the following to your `location` block:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Step 2 involves adding two pieces of code in Startup.cs.

In `ConfigurationServices(IServiceCollection services)`, add:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

In the beginning of `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`, add:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Step 2 documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1).